# ¿Cómo inhabilitar/desactivar un TextField con RadioButton?

Tags: java, javafx, interfaz-gráfica, intellij-idea, fxml

Lo que trato de hacer es que al seleccionar un Radio Button, no se pueda habilitar o se desactive el TextField.

[image: Cuando este en Efectivo debe desactivarse]

[image: Cuando este en tarjeta de debito debe activarse]

Cuando se seleccione Efectivo debe cerrarse o desactivar el TextField y cuando se seleccione la tarjeta de débito debe habilitarse:

> ```
> public void noTarjeta(){
>     rbEfectivo.setToggleGroup(group);
>     rbEfectivo.setSelected(true);
>     noTarjeta.setDisable(true);
>     rbDebito.setToggleGroup(group);
> }
> ```

Solo tengo ese método, que lo que único que hace es dejar marcar solo una opción. Lo estoy haciendo en FXML

```xml
<RadioButton fx:id="rbDebito" text="Tarjeta Debito" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
<RadioButton fx:id="rbEfectivo" text="Efectivo" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente usa la propiedad `setEditable(false)`, de esta forma se desactivara el `JTextField`:

```
public void noTarjeta(){
    rbEfectivo.setToggleGroup(group);
    rbEfectivo.setSelected(true);
    noTarjeta.setDisable(true);
    rbDebito.setToggleGroup(group);

    noTarjeta.setEditable(false); //desactiva `JTextField`
}
```

Comment: Pero cuando le doy en el radio botón de la Tarjeta de debito, no se puede editar

Answer (score 0):

Para que te funcione correctamente todas las veces que quieras bastaría con añadirles un action listener a cada radioButton.
Tendrías que asignarles su action listener a cada uno:

```
    rbDebito.addActionListener(new RbDebito());
    rbEfectivo.addActionListener(new RbEfectivo());
```

Y luego las clases RbDebito y RbEfectivo las puedes crear en tu misma clase de la siguiente manera:

```
class RbDebitoActionListener implements ActionListener{
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        noTarjeta.setEditable(true);
    }
}

class RbEfectivo implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        noTarjeta.setEditable(false);
    }
```

Esto lo añades al final del codigo de la clase en la que estes y listo

Comment: ActionListener no me aparece, solo ActionEvent y EventHandler

Answer (score 0):

**Escuchando un cambio en `ToggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty()`**

`getSelectedToggle()` de [ToggleGroup Class (javafx 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html)  se obtiene el objeto del grupo que está seleccionado , entonces se compara con un botón , si la comparación es true entonces `textField.setDisable(true)`

[image: togglegroup javafx]

La parte en cuestión esta entre comentarios en el código

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        RadioButton radioButtonA = new RadioButton("Tarjeta Débito");
        RadioButton radioButtonB = new RadioButton("Efectivo");
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Número de Tarjeta");
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        grid.setHgap(20);
        grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.add(radioButtonA, 0, 0);
        grid.add(radioButtonB, 1, 0);
        grid.add(textField, 0, 1);
        
        //_______________________________________
        
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        group.getToggles().addAll(radioButtonA,radioButtonB);
        group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((o) -> {
          textField.setDisable(group.getSelectedToggle().equals(radioButtonB));
        }); 
        //_______________________________________
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```